# Gradle. Resolved versions for compilation (x.x.x) and packaging (y.y.y) differ

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, dependency-management

There are many plugins in cordova, many of them use google play service. And each plugin want to use some special version of play services. It's really annoying.

To resolve this problem I'm trying to create simple dependencies version resolver in graddle. It should get required version from some plugin dependencies (I mean play services version) and set the same version for other plugin dependencies.

Here is my script:

```
def right_version = "9+";
configurations.all{
    resolutionStrategy{
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.name.contains('play-services') && details.requested.version != '9+') {
                right_version = details.requested.version
            }
        }
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if ( details.requested.name.contains('play-services') ){
                details.useVersion right_version
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but there is a little problem. I received errors like the following:

```
Conflict with dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads'. Resolved versions for compilation (10.2.0) and packaging (9.8.0) differ. This can generate runtime errors due to mismatched resources.
```

What is the reason? Or maybe you know better way to resolve dependencies conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a source of the problem. It's a bad idea to use eachDependency twice and to change a version in the second usage. As it appears, dependency becomes approved (or something like that) after the first eachDependency. So, all work fine with the following code:

```
def right_version = "9+";
configurations.all{
    dependencies.all{ Dependency d ->
        def right_version_copy = right_version
        if(d.getName().contains("play-services") && d.getVersion() != right_version_copy){
            right_version = d.getVersion()
        }
    }
    resolutionStrategy{
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if ( details.requested.name.contains('play-services') ){
                details.useVersion right_version
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not offline in Android studio if you are using this ide for development.You can check that as **File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Gradle**. 
Secondly, If you are using command line tools or Android studio you have to update the google play services to latest version in **build.gradle** of the *application or app* such as
**compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'** to latest as
**compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'**.
You can choose specific version of play services api instead of full google play services package from the list here [https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup][1]

Comment: The point is that some people can use my cordova plugin (which use google play services) with some other cordova plugin (with not last version of play services). So, I can't fix that problem by updating play services version in all plugins. 
And I don't use android studio for this script. I run build process via cordova CLI.

Comment: **Gradle IntelliJ** functions as wrapper which allow order google services version in  modules/library used in any plugin of cordova with latest.It is highly recommended that app module of any android/cordova application should be update to latest version of play services library.Hence older version support in library/module and new version support in app module of any application is automatically managed by Gradle itself.

Comment: I'm not sure that using the last version is the best solution. Some changes in API can kill your plugin, so I prefer to use tested major version of libraries.

Anyway, even it's a good idea, it doesn't work in real world. I know plugins with old play services (actually my users write me about issues with different versions).